# How to load files in RichTextBox control using ItemActivate event of ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to load files from a folder and listing them in the ListBox control. After that, once the user selects (double clicks) any list item(file), then it should open in the RichTextBox control.

I have tried an implementation at my end, provided below

```
public void DisplayFolder(string folderPath)
{
    listView1.Clear();
    listView1.Columns.Add("File Name", 150);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Last Accessed", 110);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Size", 80);
    listView1.Activation = ItemActivation.TwoClick;

    listView1.View = View.Details;
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] {fileName, File.GetLastAccessTime(file).ToString(), file.Length.ToString()});
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rct = (RichTextBox)((Control)sender).TopLevelControl.Controls[1];
    string filepath = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
    string fileName = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;
    rct.LoadFile(filepath + "\\" + fileName);
}
```

The file selected in the ListBox control should get loaded in the RichTextBox control.

Exception is:

> File not found exception error occurs on rct.LoadFile(filepath + "\" + fileName); code line.

Comment: What problem/error are you facing when you run this code?

Comment: File not found exception error occurs on rct.LoadFile(filepath + "\\" + fileName); code line.

Answer (score 0):

The line `string filepath = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();` will not work the way you are expecting it to. `listView1.SelectedItems` is a collection and not an individual item that points to a filepath. In addition, you are not storing the filepath anywhere in the listview.

I suggest you add the file path as per:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] {fileName, File.GetLastAccessTime(file).ToString(), file.Length.ToString(), folderPath});
```

This will add the `folderPath` to the last item in the ListView, where you can reference it later on.

Also, modifying your `_ItemActivate` handler to be as below, will get the filePath from the ListView:

```
string filepath = listView1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text;
```

Finally, when loading the file, you should make use of `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating strings, for example:

```
rct.LoadFile(Path.Combine(filepath, fileName));
```

Comment: Thank you JayV, your suggestions helped me solve the issue.